# extending DataInputStream in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've subclassed DataInputStream and added little-endian methods. Observe that I add a new `inp` property that represents the original `InputStream`. I need to reference this property in the new methods. The following code works fine:

```
import java.io.*
import org.apache.poi.util.*

class MyDataInputStream(val inp: InputStream) : DataInputStream(inp) {

    fun readShortLittle(): Short {
        val r: Short
        try {
            r = LittleEndian.readShort(inp)
        } catch (e: LittleEndian.BufferUnderrunException) {
            throw EOFException()
        }
        return r
    }

    fun readIntLittle(): Int {
        val r: Int
        try {
            r = LittleEndian.readInt(inp)
        } catch (e: LittleEndian.BufferUnderrunException) {
            throw EOFException()
        }
        return r
    }

    fun readLongLittle(): Long {
        val r: Long
        try {
            r = LittleEndian.readLong(inp)
        } catch (e: LittleEndian.BufferUnderrunException) {
            throw EOFException()
        }
        return r
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var i: Int
    val inp = MyDataInputStream(System.`in`)
    while (true) {
        // llegir int en binari si EOF break
        try {
            i = inp.readIntLittle()
        } catch (e: EOFException) {
            break
        }
        println(i);
    }
}
```

However I wonder how to do this with extension methods such as:

```
fun DataInputStream.readShortLittle(): Short {
    ...
}

fun DataInputStream.readIntLittle(): Int {
    ....
}

fun DataInputStream.readLongLittle(): Long {
    ....
}
```

I've problems when defining the new `inp` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can't, because it's accessible by a `protected` field which isn't visible to an extension method. But using `this` instead of `inp` should work because `LittleEndian.read` methods will call `read` on the `DataInputStream` which will delegate to `in.read`.